# See number of connected users?

Tags: java, android, firebase

How can we retrieve the number of connected users in Firebase? I've tried searching online but I didn't find anything relevant.

I'm still waiting for a correct answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for Firebase's internal stats on how many users are currently connected to your database, you can find that in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/usage/current-billing/connections).

Comment: Can we retrieve this number of connected users from Android?

Comment: There is no API for the Firebase console. If you want to track connected users programmatically, look at the link Siva provided.